# Pass multiple DropDownList Selected Values to controller in one variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page in my MVC3 web app that has a table with 20 or so rows in it. Each row has a dropdown in it (the same drop down for each row).

I want to be able to pass all of the dropdown SelectedValues back to my controller in one array.

I have done something similar where I had a bunch of checkboxes all named the same thing and then I was able to put int[] checkboxname in the controller signature. The same thing doesn't seem to work with dropdowns. It only ever passes 1 value back to the controller rather than an array of values.

Basically in my View, I have

```
Loop start
    @Html.DropDownList("gridMultipliers", (SelectList)ViewBag.GridMultiplierList)
Loop End
```

Then in my controller signature, I have

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(int[] gridMultipliers){
    //stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're going to have to do something more along these lines:

```
@Html.DropDownList("gridMultipliers" + i, (SelectList)ViewBag.GridMultiplierList)
```

where `i` is the loop iteration. This should then get transformed into an array when it's posted.